# Problems with auto width using CSS

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="outer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to ajust the `outer` element's width using CSS.

Here is the requirement:

1. the `outer` has a padding of `8px`
2. if `inner` is smaller than `200px - 16px`, then `outer` is `200px`
3. if `inner` is greater or equal to `200px - 16px`, then `outer`'s width is `inner's width + 16px`
4. `outer` may has children of `outer`, and the inner `outer` element has the same requirement.

For example:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="outer">
  </div>
</div>
```

the outer `outer` has a width of `200px + 16px`, the inner `outer` has a width of `200px`

Comment: You have three divs all with the ID `id="outer"` — this is illegal; an ID must be unique within the HTML document, and your CSS won't work as desired. If you have several of these, they should use a **class** not an **id** : `<div class="outer">`

Comment: @StephenP I forgot to change it to `class`. I have edited it again.

Comment: Why the arbitrary `-16px`? Where does this come from? Is this supposed to be PADDING of  `outer`? Just fyi: margin isn't part of width while padding is part of the width.

Comment: @KodosJohnson a padding of `8px`...My apology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented on TheValyreanGroup's answer on how to make his/her answer work for your purpose. Basically you just have to add `display:inline-block` to prevent the `outer` div from taking up 100% width. Here is a demonstration:

```css
.outer {
 padding:8px;
 min-width:200px;
 display:inline-block;
} 

/* These are for demonstration */
.outer {
 background-color:red;
}
.outer > .outer {
 background-color:purple;
}
.outer > .outer > .outer {
 background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner" contenteditable="true">test</div>
 <div class="outer">
  <div class="outer" contenteditable="true">test test test test test</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I added background colors just to demonstrate. I added `contenteditable="true"` so you can directly edit the text to observe its behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Use `min-width`

```
#outer{
     min-width:200px;
 }
#inner{
     width: auto;
}
```

This will cause `outer` to grow with `inner` but not below `200px`

Comment: I edited my question as I didn't make clear of my requirements. And in your answer, `#outer`'s width is the same to its outer element.(if the outer element is greater than `200px`, it will has a width greater than `200px`)

Comment: @zhuscat You can make this answer work by changing the id selectors to class selects (`#outer` -> `.outer`) and adding the following: `.outer {padding:8px;min-width:200px;display:inline-block;}`. The secret is `inline-block` which doesn't take up 100% width.